# Crontab task scheduled every hour stops running from 11am to 12am

Tags: bash, cron

I have a rather weird issue. My aim is to use ffmpeg to grab a screenshot from a home CCTV cameras rtsp stream every hour. I want to do this in order to make a timelapse. However everyday from 11am to 12am (the next day) there are no snapshots saved.

On an always on Debian machine, this is the shell script I have that crontab calls:

```
dt=$(date +"%d%m%2y%I%M%S")
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://IP:554/..." -frames 1 /user/snapshots/ch1/$dt.jpg
```

Running it by itself works fine and saves a jpg snapshot successfully to the right folders.

In `crontab -e` I have the following line:
`0 * * * * /bin/sh //user/snap.sh`

Thanks.

Comment: This is weird behaviour. Does you machine, or maybe your camera, go offline during that time? Try `0 * * * * date >> /tmp/date.log` for a day, then check if that has run every hour as expected. If so, you'd have to check if something is wrong with your camera at the hours when you're not getting images. If not, something is weird with your machine's `cron` system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%I` is the hour on a 12-hour clock (intended to be used with `%p`), so your afternoon files are overwriting the morning ones.  Use `%H` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should add something like

```
0 11-0 * * * /bin/sh //user/snap.sh
```

Mean task will start every minute 0 from every hour from 11AM to 12AM